# HTTP load failed (error code: 12 [1:12])

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, nsurlsession

In my app, I try to download a batch of images from a server.

I'm getting a number of errors, one of which I can't find an explanation for. I checked [Apple's URL loading system error codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes), but I couldn't fine one for error code 12. I also got `HTTP load failed (error code: -999)` (which is `NSURLErrorCancelled`) and `Task finished with error - code: -1001`(which is `NSURLErrorTimedOut`).

I recently switched from using deprecated NSURLConnection to NSURLSession. With the former, I also got the 999 and 1001 errors, but I'm trying to find out what error code 12 means.

```
- (void)loadImage:(LeafletURL*)leafletURLInput isThumbnail:(BOOL)isThumbnailInput isBatchDownload:(BOOL)isBatchDownload isRetina:(BOOL)isRetina
{

    isRetina_ = isRetina;

    if (session)
    {
        /*is this the right call here? */
        [session invalidateAndCancel];
        [session release];
        session = nil;
    }
    if (mImageData)
    {
        [mImageData release];
        mImageData = nil;
    }

    self.leafletURL = leafletURLInput;
    self.isThumbnail = isThumbnailInput;

    NSString* location = (self.isThumbnail) ?leafletURL.thumbnailLocation :leafletURL.hiResImageLocation;

    //// Check if the image needs to be downloaded from server. If it is a batch download, then override the local resources////
    if ( ([location isEqualToString:kLocationServer] || (isBatchDownload && [location isEqualToString:kLocationResource])) && self.leafletURL.rawURL != nil )
    {
        //NSLog(@"final loadimage called server");
        //// tell the delegate to get ride of the old image while waiting. ////
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderWillBeginLoadingImage:)])
        {
            [delegate leafletImageLoaderWillBeginLoadingImage:self];
        }

        mImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        /*download tasks have their data written to a local temp file. It’s the responsibility of the completion handler to move the file from its temporary location to a permanent location.*/

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[leafletURL pathForImageOnServerUsingThumbnail:self.isThumbnail isRetina:isRetina]];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                              completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                    {
                        // do something with the data
                    }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }

    //// if not, tell the delegate that the image is already cached. ////
    else
    {
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:)])
        {

            [delegate leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:self];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to find out what error code 12 is ?  I have the same issue as well.

Comment: @Ravi still haven't - I'll definitely post here if I do

Comment: Did you use Google or Facebook pods?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Was there ever a solution arrived at? Thanks.

Comment: When trying to understand an error code, start with the error domain.  The NSError object has a few pieces of information to describe itself.  Documentation could be better indexed, but be aware of all the available info.